# RxJava: A scan with Single based accumulator which disposes intermediate Single

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm writing an Rx-based unidirectional UI flow where each state reduce is a `Single`. Usually such flows are done with `scan` (they need previous state), but when `Single` is involved it's a bit tricky. I managed to get it working like this:

```kotlin
val events = Observable.just("event1", "event2", "event3")
val initialState = Single.just(emptyList<String>())
// given a current state produces next state's Single
val reducer = { currentState: List<String>, event: String ->
  Single.fromCallable { /* do work */ currentState.plus(event) }
}

events
  .scan(
    initialState,
    { currentStateSingle, event ->
      val nextStateSingle = currentStateSingle
        .flatMap { curState -> reducer(curState, event) }
      // cache is required to avoid resubscription 
      // to all previously emitted single's on each new scan iteration
      nextStateSingle.cache()
    }
  )
  .flatMapSingle { it }
  .subscribe { state -> println("state updated to $state") }
```

What bothers me is that each event (of which there can be *many* in UI environment) will create a `nextStateSingle.cache()` and *forever* add it to an existing chain and all those `Single`s ever emitted will stay there, unboundedly consuming memory and never being disposed while after they emitted a new state once, they are not needed at all.

I've been thinking on how to do this with some kind of `switchMap` usage, or even using some external atomic variable to hold state (instead of scan), but I fail to find a way.

The only other option I see is to write a custom operator which will subscribe to inner single, wait for result then dispose it, but I'd like to avoid writing a custom operator.

Comment: May I enquire the purpose of wrapping each state in a `Single` and not just concatenate the State?

Comment: For example it can be an IO bound operation which takes some time to complete.

Comment: But you already have an `Observable` though, so you can already handle IO bound operations through `Schedulers`. I've never seen this nested structure Single inside Observable before to be honest, and I would not approach the problem this way. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. It is quite common actually, for example as a reaction to user input one might want to perform some network request which would send this input to the server, return with result and only then, based on this result, new state might be obtained.

Comment: That's MVI right? The network request takes place before you reach the `scan` though, then you use the reducer, whereas you are subscribing to the emitted Singles at this point `.flatMapSingle { it }`. The concept as you said is very common yet your solution for this problem is quite "unique" if you compare it with this one for instance which is more standard: https://proandroiddev.com/unidirectional-data-flow-with-roxie-bec546c18598

Comment: You can say this is MVI (as known in android land), but in general this is a pattern popularized as The Elm Architecture. We've been doing the form you describe for years, it works, but I'd like to extend and generalize it so that reducer can produce the state as a deferred action, in form of Single in this example. In Haskell this would be an IO action, in Elm — the Cmd. Example above demostrates that it could be easily done, I just want to sort out potential memory issues.

Comment: @ExpensiveBelly it hit me that you are right and nothing prevents me from lifting up this Single to be run on each event emitted by Observable, *unless* that Single depends on previous state. So this is the thing I'm trying to explore here. Otherwise we have done this exactly the way you've described.

Comment: in MVI what you call the previous State is the "current" state, because the new state has not been emitted yet. You should be able to get it.

Comment: Nope, not from outside the scan operator. In proper MVI implementation state doesn't leak outside the Rx chain.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of cache, since you can't dispose the origin and you can't clear the cached values you can use this workaround which can control the cache and clear chached values by forgetting all references:

```
AtomicBoolean shouldStop = new AtomicBoolean();

source.takeUntil(v -> shouldStop.get())
        .onTerminateDetach()
        .cache()
        .takeUntil(v -> shouldStop.get())
        .onTerminateDetach()
        .subscribe(...);
```

Then maybe you can save the state and nulls out references once in a while.

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem of using `cache()` operator (which I discourage), which will re-throw the error upon subscription if an error happens in that `source`. Also, we're starting to take state out of the stream...

Comment: I think both problems are downsides of using cache, but, the question was more about reducing memory consumption and not to suggest a whole new design.